# Unable to setup Gandalf Go

Tags: go, testing

I am trying to setup Gandalf but when I do `go get github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/Gandalf` I'm getting error

```
package github.com/jmartin82/mmock/definition: cannot find package "github.com/jmartin82/mmock/definition" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jmartin82/mmock/definition (from $GOROOT)
        <My_Go_Path>/src/github.com/jmartin82/mmock/definition (from $GOPATH)
```

[I'm using testing file from](https://github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/Gandalf/tree/master/examples/goserver)

Comment: `go get github.com/jmartin82/mmock` ?

Comment: @mh-cbon yeah i tried `go get github.com/jmartin82/mmock` and than `go get github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/Gandalf` but same issue. also I tried checking on the repo `github.com/jmartin82/mmock/definition` but getting 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reached me via a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/Gandalf/issues/37) however I thought it best to mention it here for clarity.

Gandalf utilizes go modules to pin dependency versions, `go get` will download the latest version of a dependency rather than the version a project actually supports where as something like `go mod download` will respect the `go.mod` file and fetch the correct version. The mmock project has changed its package structure making newer versions of it not backwards compatible.

I recommend getting antiquated with go modules as they seem to be the way forward now and have been enabled by default in newer versions of the go compiler. If I remember correctly you may already have support for it you just need to set the environment variable `GO111MODULE=on` when dealing with projects that have a `go.mod` file.